# Change to a directory containing a space

Tags: bash, shell, filenames, cd-command, whitespace

I'm using a MacBook with OS X installed.

I'm on Terminal trying to go to a directory. So I'm in Home and I use the command `ls` and there is a `VirtualBox VMs` directory.

But when I try to do `cd VirtualBox VMs` it says "No such file or directory"

Why?

Is it because of the space bar in the word? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's because of the space character. Use

```
cd 'VirtualBox VMs'
```

or

```
cd VirtualBox\ VMs
```

Comment: @GrangerObliviate Note that `bash`'s filename completion (e.g. type `cd Virt<TAB>`) will not only complete the filename for you, it will quote or escape it for you if necessary.